# creating summarized data from two separate dictionaries in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the below data in a pandas dataframe,where each section belongs to a class and also a student can take some premium classes separately or as included in a class.

```
student_id  Section A   Section B   Section C   Section D   Prem 1  Prem 2  Section E   Prem 3  Section F
1               0           12          0           1           9       0       24          12      45
2               9           19          24          24          2       29      25          4       24
3               19          24          26          18          20      0       2           0       17
4               26          11          29          11          28      1       18          25      4
5               14          23          11          8           17      6       1           25      14
```

I have two dictionaries:
class_dict : which contains the sections and premium together as part of package.

```
Class A :   {Section A, Section B, Prem 1}                              
Class B :   {Section C, Section D, Section E}                               
Class C:    {Section F, Prem 2, Prem 3}
```

prem_dict : which contains only the premium classes.

```
Premiums : { Prem 1, Prem 2, Prem 3}
```

The values are monthly hours spent.

I need to find out the total hours within each class separately from the premium classes and also the number of premium classes taken.

So the expected output for the above data is:

```
student_id  Class A Class B Class C Premium Number of Premium
1               12      25      45      21      2
2               28      73      24      35      3
3               43      46      17      22      2
4               37      58      4       54      3
5               37      20      14      48      3
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I do not understand your output.First student 0+12=12,but how do you have two premiums?

Comment: hi @RichardRublev, the first student is 9+0+12 for premium and hence 2 premium classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe inputs are `dictionaries of list`s:

```
d1 = {'Class A' :   ['Section A', 'Section B', 'Prem 1'],                             
     'Class B' :   ['Section C', 'Section D', 'Section E'],                              
     'Class C':    ['Section F', 'Prem 2', 'Prem 3']}

d2 = {'Premiums' : ['Prem 1', 'Prem 2', 'Prem 3']}
```

Swap values of lists with keys and filter out `Prem` values for first dict:

```
d11 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d1.items() for k in oldv if not 'Prem' in k} 
d21 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d2.items() for k in oldv}
```

Join dictionaries together:

```
d3 = {**d11, **d21}
```

Group by columns with final dictionary and aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(d3, axis=1).sum()
```

Last add column for count non `0` Premium columns:

```
df1['no_of_prem']= df[['Prem 1','Prem 2','Prem 3']].ne(0).sum(axis=1)
print (df1)
   Class A  Class B  Class C  Premiums  no_of_prem
0       12       25       45        21           2
1       28       73       24        35           3
2       43       46       17        20           1
3       37       58        4        54           3
4       37       20       14        48           3
```

---

Another solution is create `tuple`s from `dictinaries`, join them together:

```
L1 = [(oldk, k) for oldk, oldv in d1.items() for k in oldv if not 'Prem' in k] 
L2 = [(oldk, k) for oldk, oldv in d2.items() for k in oldv]
```

Then create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html), [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) columns for first level used for aggregate [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L1 + L2)
df1 = df.reindex(columns=mux, level=1).sum(level=0, axis=1)
df1['no_of_prem']= df[['Prem 1','Prem 2','Prem 3']].ne(0).sum(axis=1)
print (df1)
   Class B  Class C  Class A  Premiums  no_of_prem
0       25       45       12        21           2
1       73       24       28        35           3
2       46       17       43        20           1
3       58        4       37        54           3
4       20       14       37        48           3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply to directly add no of hours.

```
df['prem_no']=df.apply(lambda x : (x['prem1']+x['prem2']+x['prem3']), axis=1)
```

To count no of premiums you can use

```
df['no_of_prem']= (df[['prem1','prem2','prem3']] !=0 ).astype(int).sum(axis=1)
```